# How to use the k means algorithm by importing data from JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary, k-means

I'm trying to use the k-means algorithm for some data contained within JSON files.
If, for example, I had multiple JSON files similar to this (example_file1.JSON) where each JSON file contained a different numeric value of "provides", how could I apply the k-means algorithm to the values ​​of "provides" (with the value of k varying between 3 and 8)??

Example_file1.JSON

```
{
  "Accenture": {
    "platform": 0,
    "provides": 2,
    "government": 0,
    "through": 1,
    "clients": 0,
    "business": 1,
    "financial": 0,
    "services": 2,
    "information": 0,
    "research": 0,
    "health": 0,
  },...
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [sklearn.kmeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html). As already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49068022/using-k-means-clustering-to-cluster-based-on-single-variable), you need to parse all the json and create a numpy array containing the features (in your case the value of "provides"), and then use it to fit the kmeans.

EDIT:

Let's provide a more complete answer:

```
import random
import string
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# Create a test set of input json
N = 100
rng = np.random.default_rng()
numbers = rng.choice(N + 1, N // 2, replace=False)      # Let's create 2 cluster

json_files = list()
for idx in range(N):
    new_json = dict()
    for _ in range(4):
        new_json["".join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(10))] = random.randint(0, 5)
    if idx in numbers:
        new_json["provides"] = random.uniform(0, 5)         # First cluster is between 0 and 5
    else:
        new_json["provides"] = random.uniform(10, 15)       # Second cluster is between 10 and 15
    json_files.append({"Accenture": new_json})
```

This way, we created a generic set of 100 input json file. Each one of them has different entries with random keys. For half of them we've inserted some values between 0-5 (to get a clear first cluster), for the other half 10-15.

```
# Let's visualize it
X = np.array([json["Accenture"]["provides"] for json in json_files])
Y = np.ones(len(X))
plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

[image: Setup plot]

The setup is pretty clean, let's perform the actual k-means:

```
model = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
model.fit(X.reshape(-1, 1))         # Reshape is needed if you have only 1 feature
prediction = model.predict(X.reshape(-1, 1))

plt.scatter(X[prediction == 1], Y[prediction == 1], c="green")
plt.scatter(X[prediction == 0], Y[prediction == 0], c="red")
plt.show()
```

[image: After K-means]

Which is the expected result. In the `predicted` variable you now have the labels for each json file.

Comment: So imaging you have (example_file1.JSON, example_file2.JSON,example_file3.JSON, etc..), how could I go about employing the k-means algorithm?

Example_file1.JSON
{
  "Accenture": {
    "platform": 0,
    "provides":2,
  },...
}

Example_file2.JSON

{
  "Accenture": {
    "platform": 0,
    "provides": 4,
    "government": 0,
    "through": 1,
  },...
}

Example_file3:JSON

{
  "Accenture": {
    "platform": 0,
    "provides": 7,
    "government": 0,
    "through": 1,
    "clients": 0,
    "business": 1
  },...
}